# Finding Microsoft Graph Scopes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Since Graph is a self-documenting language, I wanted to use this to my advantage and write PowerShell functions to automatically generate cmdlets based on metadata. I've got a lot of this complete, but am having problems figuring out scopes. Is there a way to find scopes? It's not stored in the metadata and the documentation doesn't have scopes listed for everything (for instance, nothing in Excel has scopes listed).

The Graph Explorer seems to request correct permissions, so that has access to this list somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which API you are looking for.

Scopes for Azure AD Graph API is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes.

There is a huge list for different parts of the Microsoft Graph API at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/permission_scopes.

When you first sign in to Graph Explorer, you give it these permissions:
[image: Graph Explorer permissions]

Based on the descriptions and the link above you can figure out what the scope name is for each of the items in the list. (E.g. the first one is Mail.ReadWrite).

When you create an application in Azure AD, you configure which applications it needs access to, and what access it needs. That results in the list which the user grants access to on first signin.

Comment: Actually, the Graph Explorer was updated since my answer yesterday. You can now modify which permission scopes you want it to request: https://dev.office.com/blogs/microsoft-graph-explorer-updated-with-sample-queries

Comment: The problem with this is I'm creating cmdlets to potentially interact with all of Graph. I think for now I'll create a configuration file with all the scopes I know of for my cmdlets and allow the user to specify their own. The hope was to not require the end user to figure out what scope they need, but I guess that piece can't be helped for now.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small function to enumerate all Microsoft Graph API permissions (based on [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http#retrieve-permission-ids-through-microsoft-graph)). Requires `jq` for now, there's probably a way to do this 100% in PowerShell but this was a quick and dirty fix. You can further pipe to `grep` to assist in finding the permissions you need.

Add this function to your `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` (`$PROFILE`) for convenience:

```
function Get-MgGraph-Scopes {
  $uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')?$select=id,appId,displayName,appRoles,oauth2PermissionScopes,resourceSpecificApplicationPermissions"
  Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -OutputType Json |
  jq -r '.appRoles + .oauth2PermissionScopes | .[] | .value'
}
```

Example use:

```
PS > Get-MgGraph-Scopes | grep -i calendar
Calendars.Read
Calendars.ReadBasic.All
Calendars.ReadWrite
Calendars.Read
Calendars.Read.Shared
Calendars.ReadBasic
Calendars.ReadWrite
Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared
```